How to open a 2Go .dta file with python?
I have been working with really large databases with R. I now want to exploit them with python since my mac is quite old (HighSierra) and doesn't allow to charge the module binsreg on RStudio. This package also exists in python. However since my .dta are very heavy, I keep not being able to open them, even when trying to load them by chunks. Would someone be able to tell me if opening a 2Go .dta file is just not possible with my laptop (4Go processing memory) ? I am not used to these consideration, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks !
I did try to load my .dta by chunks and put them in a panda dataframe by chunks, but I feel like this is not a solution. Pyreadstat always charges the file as a whole (if I understand right).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
